# Can't display gauge chart inside a jquery get

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I can't get to display a google gauge chart, using the values I retrieve inside a jquery get. If I set the values statically the chart shows up, otherwise it just doesn't appear.
This happens even though I can succesfully print the variables, so it is not a matter of variables not being correctly set.

The dataset is enclosed between "#", and separated by ";", like:

## value1;value2;value3;....;value7

I have tried setting the variables statically, assigning them to an integer, and the chart shows up.
The console.log prints the values in either ways, this is what puzzles me.

```
$.get("index.php", function(response) 
{  
    var a=response.split("#")[1].split(";")[1].split(".")[0];
    var b=response.split("#")[1].split(";")[2].split(".")[0];
    var c=response.split("#")[1].split(";")[7].split(".")[0];
    /*  
    a=224;
    b=661;
    c=100;
    */
            
    console.log(a + " " + b + " " + c); 
    data_gauge = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['a',a],
    ['b',b],
    ['c',c]
    ]);
    
    
    var options_gauge = {
        width: 400, height: 130,
        redFrom: 1000, redTo: 5000,
        yellowFrom:100, yellowTo: 1000,
        minorTicks: 2,
        max: 7000,
        min: 0
        };

    try{
        var chart_gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('div_gauge'));
        chart_gauge.draw(data_gauge, options_gauge);
    }
    catch(e)
    {console.log(e.message)}
},"text");
```

I thought the issue could have been related to the jquery call, but since the console.log shows the 3 variables have their respective values, I don't understand what's wrong. It is like the google chart is not accepting the data coming from the GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely the values are being stored as strings, instead of numbers.
when this is the case, the chart will not draw, and no errors are recorded.

use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to ensure the values are numbers.

```
var a=parseFloat(response.split("#")[1].split(";")[1].split(".")[0]);
```

see following working examples...

1) drawn with strings (nothing happens)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gauge'],
}).then(function () {
  var a='224';
  var b='661';
  var c='100';

  console.log(a + " " + b + " " + c);
  data_gauge = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['a',a],
    ['b',b],
    ['c',c]
  ]);


  var options_gauge = {
    width: 400, height: 130,
    redFrom: 1000, redTo: 5000,
    yellowFrom:100, yellowTo: 1000,
    minorTicks: 2,
    max: 7000,
    min: 0
  };

  var chart_gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('div_gauge'));
  chart_gauge.draw(data_gauge, options_gauge);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div_gauge"></div>
```

---

2) drawn with numbers (chart appears)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gauge'],
}).then(function () {
  var a=parseFloat('224');
  var b=parseFloat('661');
  var c=parseFloat('100');

  console.log(a + " " + b + " " + c);
  data_gauge = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['a',a],
    ['b',b],
    ['c',c]
  ]);


  var options_gauge = {
    width: 400, height: 130,
    redFrom: 1000, redTo: 5000,
    yellowFrom:100, yellowTo: 1000,
    minorTicks: 2,
    max: 7000,
    min: 0
  };

  var chart_gauge = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('div_gauge'));
  chart_gauge.draw(data_gauge, options_gauge);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div_gauge"></div>
```

Comment: I eventually sorted it out. It turned out the first element of the splitted string, produced something weird, whereas the other elements were correctly defined as numbers. I parsed the element by dividing it to 1, and this fixed the issue. But I guess your suggestion is much elegant, as well as effective.